# Tyre recommendation

Tags: tire, specialized-bikes

I recently purchased a second hand [Specialized Enduro](https://bikes.fan/specialized-enduro-comp-650b-2016/) Bike model.

Anyway the tyres are pretty worn out, and I was wondering what would you recommend for a full suspenison bike. I plan to ride on mountain trails on weekends, and easy to medium trails on a daily basis.

Can you recommend me some tyres? My preferences at the moment are Continental Mountain King with Black Chili compound, or Maxxis Forekaster.

Would you think that this tyres would be appropiate for my riding style?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Welcome to the site - please do take a moment to browse the [tour] and learn how Stackexchange works.  Sadly this is a good example of a shopping question, which are off-topic because they are of limited use in time, and often have regional bias.  **As written** this question will probably be closed.

Comment: However, I can't find an existing Q&A that asks "how to choose a tread pattern for my riding and terrain?"   So [edit] to be less shopping and more "how to choose" would be good.   Example for someone asking specifically about MTB slicks https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/how-to-choose-a-set-of-tyres

Comment: Example of someone asking how to choose a quality of tyre   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/53785/how-do-i-shop-for-a-good-tire

Comment: Example asking about tyre width  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: But we don't have an existing question asking how to choose a tread pattern, and what the advantages or disadvantages are.

Comment: Make the question more general and I will provide you with an answer.

Comment: I am also looking at buying a new tire. I am hoping for links to a site where they do compare tires and keep it up to date. (I agree that doing it here will not work, to many variables.) I know a Dutch language forum where they try to answer the question and even there they run in 'out of stock now' on most popular tires from the recent past.